# ng-grid + rowTemplate not working. What am I missing?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am attempting to add ngdblclick elements to each row with my ng-grid.  It works! However, I can no longer see my data.  I can see the rows but no data. The data is there an it seems to be binding correctly.  I know this because I created a list called selectedRows that binds to the selectedItems in gridOptions.  When I click on the each row.  I see my data displayed within an html

```
 tag. See below for my code.
```

`$scope.tableData=[];

$scope.tableData=[{id:'10203040', status:'Submitted'},
              {id:'10203040', status:'Submitted'},]

$scope.selectedRows=[];

var rowTempl = '<div ng-dblClick="onDblClickRow(row)" ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor   }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" '+'ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell{{col.cellClass}}"><div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height:rowHeight}" ng-class"{ngVerticalBarVisible:!$last}">$nbsp;</div><div ng-cell></div></div>';

$scope.onDblClickRow = function(row){
 alert("Double Click works!");
};


$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    selectedItems:$scope.selectedRows,
    showColumnMenu:true,
    showFilter:false,
    enableColumnResize:true,
    enableRowSelection:true,
    showGroupPanel:false,
    rowTemplate: rowTempl,
    columnDefs: [
      {displayName:'Name', field:'name'},
      {displayName:'Age', field:'age'}],
   };
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to run your code. Your columDefs field and your tableData keys do not match. Also, gridOptions data has 'myData' instead of 'tableData'. I'm not sure what code you used since you say that you could see the data in HTML.

Anyway, this works:

```
$scope.tableData=[];

$scope.tableData=[{id:'10203040', status:'Submitted'},
              {id:'10203040', status:'Submitted'}];

$scope.selectedRows=[];

var rowTempl = '<div ng-dblClick="onDblClickRow(row)" ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor   }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" '+'ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell{{col.cellClass}}"><div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height:rowHeight}" ng-class"{ngVerticalBarVisible:!$last}">$nbsp;</div><div ng-cell></div></div>';

$scope.onDblClickRow = function(row){
 alert("Double Click works!");
};


$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'tableData',
    selectedItems:$scope.selectedRows,
    showColumnMenu:true,
    showFilter:false,
    enableColumnResize:true,
    enableRowSelection:true,
    showGroupPanel:false,
    rowTemplate: rowTempl,
    columnDefs: [
      {displayName:'Name', field:'id'},
      {displayName:'Age', field:'status'}],
   };
```

Comment: Hey @Cabel, thanks for responding. When I submitted that question I had just begun playing with JS, Angularjs and ngGrid. As you saw in my code I had a lot missing. I eventually figured out what I was doing wrong. However, this is still a good example for those who stumble across this page. Thanks again.